# Numerically finding a curve that satisfies an underdetermined set of equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, physics

I am trying to determine a phase diagram along the lines of Fig 3. or Fig 4. of this [pubilcation](https://www.pnas.org/doi/pdf/10.1073/pnas.2100099118?download=true).
[image]
[image]
The curves plotted are binodals and are determined by the conditions of equality of chemical potentials of each component in all phases and equality of osmotic pressure in each phase (Section 4 of the [SI](https://www.pnas.org/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1073%2Fpnas.2100099118&file=pnas.2100099118.sapp.pdf) is a good primer).

As an example, I use free energy function similar to the one defined in the paper (although the one I am actually interested in a bit more complex. Ideally I can come up with a solution that is robust and generally applicable). This is still a good starting point because my system does reduce to this under certain limits.

We narrow our attention to the case of two solutes (1 solvent) and 2 phases.
Then we wish to find the locus of points in ($\phi_a,\phi_b$) for which the following conditions hold

$$\mu_a^{(1)} (\phi^{(1)}_a,\phi^{(1)}_b) = \mu_a^{(2)} (\phi^{(2)}_a,\phi^{(2)}_b)$$
$$\mu_b^{(1)} (\phi^{(1)}_a,\phi^{(1)}_b) = \mu_b^{(2)} (\phi^{(2)}_a,\phi^{(2)}_b)$$
$$\Pi^{(1)} (\phi^{(1)}_a,\phi^{(1)}_b) = \Pi^{(2)} (\phi^{(2)}_a,\phi^{(2)}_b)$$

Essentially, we have 4 unknowns $\phi^{(1)}_a,\phi^{(1)}_b, \phi^{(0)}_a,\phi^{(0)}_b$ and 3 equations. Subscripts here in my notation label the components and superscripts the phase. The solutions should look like the curves present in Fig 3 or Fig 4 of the linked publication (depending on parameter values). The conditions described above should be equivalent to equations (39)-(41) in this [SI](https://www.pnas.org/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1073%2Fpnas.2100099118&file=pnas.2100099118.sapp.pdf)

Here are the function definitions

```
     F[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
     a/na*Log[a] + b/nb*Log[b] + (1 - a - b)*Log[1 - a - b + 10^-14] - 
      1/2*uaa*a^2 - 1/2*ubb*b^2 - uab*b*a 

    det[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
     Det[D[F[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb], {{a, b}, 2}]] // Evaluate
    \[Mu]a[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
     D[F[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb], a] // Evaluate
    \[Mu]b[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
     D[F[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb], b] // Evaluate
   \[CapitalPi]F[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, 
  nb_] := \[Mu]a[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb]*
    a + \[Mu]b[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb]*b - 
   F[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb] // Evaluate
```

My first thought was to use `NSolve`

```
    NSolve[{\[Mu]a[a1, b1, 0, 0, 4.36, 10, 6] == \[Mu]a[a2, b2, 0, 0, 
    4.36, 10, 6],
  \[Mu]b[a1, b1, 0, 0, 4.36, 10, 6] == \[Mu]b[a2, b2, 0, 0, 4.36, 10, 
    6],
  \[CapitalPi]F[a1, b1, 0, 0, 4.36, 10, 6] == \[CapitalPi]F[a2, b2, 0,
     0, 4.36, 10, 6], a1 >= 0, b1 >= 0, a2 >= 0, b2 >= 0, 
  a2 + b2 <= 1, a1 + b1 <= 1
  }, {a1, b1, a2, b2}, Reals]
```

but it seems like that is not the right way to do it.

Alternatively, I thought of using `FindRoot` combined with grid search in the region, but I am not quite sure how to implement it, or if it is the optimum most efficient way to solve this problem. An intelligent way of choosing seed values for `FindRoot` might be to use the spinodal which can be visualized as follows. Since if I understand correctly the binodal curve we are interested in should envelop this so we can try seeding points on the exterior of this?

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[det[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, 10, 6] == 0,
  {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}],
 {uaa, 0, 10}, {uab, 0, 10}, {ubb, 0, 10}]
```

**Q1** : Is there any other built-in function in mathematica that can help me solve my problem?
**Q2** : If not are there any standard approaches/algorithms that can be applied to this situation ?

**EDIT** : Partially Cross-posted [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76977991/numerically-finding-a-curve-that-satisfies-an-underdetermined-set-of-equations). Includes a janky-python brute force solution attempt using a grid search I attempted.

Comment: Why not to use equations (1), (2), (3) from the paper cited?

Comment: Thank you for engaging in discussion. yes, putting $i=1,2$ in those partial derivatives and eliminating the $\eta, \pi $ terms reduces to (39)-(41) from the paper's SI (linked above) or the definitions I have here?

Comment: I notice there is a slight mismatch in the notation. in equations (1)-(3) in the paper, the subscript $i$ denotes the phase.

Comment: We can directly minimize `F` as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for your response. I am not quite sure by what you mean. I can get the spinodal which is the det(hessian(F)) already. But the binodal curve would be determined by the equality of chemical potentials?

Comment: I mean that equations (1), (2), (3) are constraints for optimization problem for `F`. As I understand from discussion about data shown in Figure 2, they simulate some biological noise.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I see. Indeed, I think the main objective is to min F subject to constraints that the total number of molecules of each species, is constant. A typical trick is to transform the F (free energy) to the grand potential via Legendre transform (eq. 27 in the SI). Then simple min. of the grand potential yields the conditions on equality of chemical potentials that I quote here. If I understand your suggestion, it is to directly perform the constrained optimization for `F` instead of using (1),(2) and (3) (or equivalently, the equations I quote?)

Comment: i.e directly working with eq. (4) quoted in the main text, equivalent to the `F` that I have defined?

Comment: Since we have two or more phases we should minimize total free energy. For example, $V_1F(\phi_1,\psi_1)+V_2F(\phi_2,\psi_2)$ for a given volume $V_1+V_2=V$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Let us focus on the 2-phase co-existence. You are correct in the equation that you quoted. And this conservation of volume let's us derive the equality of osmotic pressure in each phase equation. However, we additionally need the constraint that the total number of molecules of each type are also conserved. See,  "[..] function (,) contains all of the information needed to characterize the equilibrium state of the system, which minimizes the total free energy of the system, subject to the constraint that the total numbers of molecules of each type are conserved."

Comment: But yes, overall solving the constrained minimization of `F` is equivalent to solving the sets of equations I quoted. However, my question remains, how does one carry that out to reproduce the curves in the paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute data shown in Figure 4 from the paper cited using `NMinimize` and expression for the free energy as follows

```
lst = Join[{{0, 0}}, 
  Table[{x, x Log[x]}, {x, 10^-3, 1, 10^-3}]]; xlog = 
 Interpolation[lst];

F[a_, b_] := 
  Module[{uaa = 0, ubb = 0, uab = 4.36, na = 10, nb = 6, F, mua, mub, 
    PiF, det}, 
   1/na*xlog[a] + 1/nb*xlog[b] + xlog[1 - a - b] - 1/2*uaa*a^2 - 
    1/2*ubb*b^2 - uab*b*a];


freeE[x_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_, p1_, 
   p2_] := {x F[a1, b1] + (1 - x) F[a2, b2], {x >= 0, x <= 1, a1 >= 0,
     a2 >= 0, b1 >= 0, b2 >= 0, a1 <= 1, b1 <= 1, a2 <= 1, b2 <= 1, 
    x a1 + (1 - x) a2 == p1, x b1 + (1 - x) b2 == p2}};

r = Range[0, .5, .0025]; Do[p2 = .05 i; 
 ls[i] = Table[{a1, b1, a2, b2, x} /. 
     NMinimize[
       freeE[x, a1, b1, a2, b2, p1, p2], {a1, b1, a2, b2, x}][[2]] // 
    Quiet, {p1, r}];, {i, 7}];
```

Visualization

```
Show[ListPlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ls[i][[All, 1]], ls[i][[All, 2]]}], {i, 7}], 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi]", "\[Psi]"}], 
 ListPlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ls[i][[All, 3]], ls[i][[All, 4]]}], {i, 7}], 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Same picture we compute at `uab = 3.8` and combine two pictures as

[image: Figure 2]

**Update 1**. To compute data shown in Figure 3 we use code

```
lst = Join[{{0, 0}}, 
  Table[{x, x Log[x]}, {x, 10^-3, 1, 10^-3}]]; xlog = 
 Interpolation[lst];

F[a_, b_] := 
  Module[{uaa = 1.8, ubb = 0, uab = 0, na = 10, nb = 6, F, mua, mub, 
    PiF, det}, 
   1/na*xlog[a] + 1/nb*xlog[b] + xlog[1 - a - b] - 1/2*uaa*a^2 - 
    1/2*ubb*b^2 - uab*b*a];


freeE[x_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_, p1_, 
   p2_] := {x F[a1, b1] + (1 - x) F[a2, b2], {x >= 0, x <= 1, a1 >= 0,
     a2 >= 0, b1 >= 0, b2 >= 0, a1 <= 1, b1 <= 1, a2 <= 1, b2 <= 1, 
    x a1 + (1 - x) a2 == p1, x b1 + (1 - x) b2 == p2}};

r = Range[0, 1, .0125]; Do[p2 = If[.1 i - p1 > 0, .1 i - p1, 0]; 
 ls[i] = Table[{a1, b1, a2, b2, x} /. 
     NMinimize[
       freeE[x, a1, b1, a2, b2, p1, p2], {a1, b1, a2, b2, x}][[2]] // 
    Quiet, {p1, r}];, {i, 0, 10, 1}];
```

Visualization

```
Show[ListPlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ls[i][[All, 1]], ls[i][[All, 2]]}], {i, 0, 10, 1}],
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi]", "\[Psi]"}], 
 ListPlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ls[i][[All, 3]], ls[i][[All, 4]]}], {i, 0, 10, 1}],
   PlotRange -> All]]
```

And the same picture we compute for `uaa = 1.3`, finally we have
[image: Figure 3]

**Update 2.** We can use equations for $\mu_a, \mu_b, \Pi$ as a filter for solutions computed above as follows

```
lst = Join[{{0, 0}}, 
  Table[{x, x Log[x]}, {x, 10^-3, 1, 10^-3}]]; xlog = 
 Interpolation[lst];

fun = Module[{uaa = 1.3, ubb = 0, uab = 0, na = 10, nb = 6, F, mua, 
    mub, PiF, det}, 
   F = a/na*Log[a] + b/nb*Log[b] + (1 - a - b)*Log[1 - a - b] - 
     1/2*uaa*a^2 - 1/2*ubb*b^2 - uab*b*a;
   det = Det[D[F, {{a, b}, 2}]];
   mua = D[F, a];
   mub = D[F, b];
   PiF = mua*a + mub*b - F; {mua, mub, PiF, det, F}];

F[a_, b_] := 
  Module[{uaa = 1.3, ubb = 0, uab = 0, na = 10, nb = 6, F, mua, mub, 
    PiF, det}, 
   1/na*xlog[a] + 1/nb*xlog[b] + xlog[1 - a - b] - 1/2*uaa*a^2 - 
    1/2*ubb*b^2 - uab*b*a];


freeE[x_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_, p1_, 
   p2_] := {x F[a1, b1] + (1 - x) F[a2, b2], {x >= 0, x <= 1, a1 >= 0,
     a2 >= 0, b1 >= 0, b2 >= 0, a1 <= 1, b1 <= 1, a2 <= 1, b2 <= 1, 
    x a1 + (1 - x) a2 == p1, x b1 + (1 - x) b2 == p2}};

r = Range[0, 1, 1/40]; r1 = Range[0, 9/10, 1/30]; Do[
 p2 = If[i - p1 > 0, i - p1, 0]; 
 sol[i, p1] = 
  NMinimize[freeE[x, a1, b1, a2, b2, p1, p2], {a1, b1, a2, b2, x}][[
    2]] // Quiet;, {p1, r}, {i, r1}];

eqmua1 = fun[[1]] /. {a -> a1, b -> b1}; eqmua2 = 
 fun[[1]] /. {a -> a2, b -> b2};

eqmua = eqmua1 - eqmua2 // Simplify;

eqmub1 = fun[[2]] /. {a -> a1, b -> b1}; eqmub2 = 
 fun[[2]] /. {a -> a2, b -> b2};

eqmub = eqmub1 - eqmub2 // Simplify;
eqpi1 = fun[[3]] /. {a -> a1, b -> b1}; eqpi2 = 
 fun[[3]] /. {a -> a2, b -> b2};

eqpi = eqpi1 - eqpi2 // Simplify

Do[ls[i] = 
    Table[If[(Norm[{eqmua, eqmub, eqpi}] /. sol[i, p1] /. 
         Indeterminate -> 1) <= 10^-3, {a1, b1, a2, b2, x} /. 
       sol[i, p1], Nothing], {p1, r}];, {i, r1}];
```

Visualization

```
Show[ListPlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ls[i][[All, 1]], ls[i][[All, 2]]}], {i, r1}], 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"\[Phi]", "\[Psi]"}], 
 ListPlot[
  Table[Transpose[{ls[i][[All, 3]], ls[i][[All, 4]]}], {i, r1}], 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: I am grateful for your efforts. Let me make sure if I understand correctly, `freeE[x_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_, p1_, 
   p2_]` this is the objective function for the minimisation routing, where you use this line `x F[a1, b1] + (1 - x) F[a2, b2]` to enforce $V_1f_1 = V_2 f_2$ ? I don't quite follow the the what the variables `p1` `p2` are doing? Are they the equal composition in each phase constraints?

Comment: Then you are taking some slices at `p2` and for each slices choosing a corresponding constraint for `p1` from `r` and then find the optimum `a1,a2,b1,b2,x`?

Comment: Any ideas on how to deal with the noisy points in your visualization and the horizontal lines that don't lie on the binodal curve? also, if this method is robust and can work for $\chi_{\phi,\phi} = 1.3, 1.8$ plots as well? Thank you for your tremendous efforts.

Comment: @jcp Please, note, that $x=V_1/V, 1-x=V_2/V, p_1=\bar{\phi}, p_2=\bar {\psi}$ in equations (43), (44), (45).

Comment: @jcp I don't understand your remarks about noise. Do you prefer sketch they show in Figure 4? It depends on parametrization. I used simple model with isolines `p2=const`. They used something like `p2=const +p1`. We don't know how they filtered noise.